# NodeJS infinite GET requests

Tags: php, node.js, cron, request, intervals

Sorry for my bad English.

I would like to build realtime Steam statistic app using redis `key => value` storage.

I'll store Steam user's API keys (They would insert them manually) then I need to send GET request every second to retrieve user information.

Is it a good idea to use nodejs server for this? What if users length would be higher than 100? My server won't break with large number of requests? Thanks for any advices in advance! As I understand I need infinite loop? Because CRON Job minimum interval is 1minute. Too many for me. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use sockets instead?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh Sockets are for future. Currently I want to send GET requests. After request I will send socket with user data to my website.

Comment: unclear : what do you  need to do every second ?  per user ?  Do you need to get stuff from Steam ? or from users ? or to users ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I need to update user information realtime, get user inventory, etc... I'm building "SteamBot"... Yes, per user.

Comment: so , does Steam provide an api which is meant to be poked every second/per user , or do they have an api where you can batch the refresh ? Doing stuff like a 1-second ticker process is fairly easy with node. Question is volume.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Steam has API for that. Daily limit per user is 100.000. If I run GET request every second, I'll use only 86400 requests.